# ASP.NET DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged event not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a basic drop down list. Upon selection of an item in the list, I expect to update the label with the choice of drop down list. But my code section does not show any update. Here is the code:

MainPage.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        // Use integers to index each item. Each item is a string.
        Dictionary<int, string> fruit = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        fruit.Add(1, "Kiwi");
        fruit.Add(2, "Pear");
        fruit.Add(3, "Mango");
        fruit.Add(4, "Blueberry");
        fruit.Add(5, "Apricot");
        fruit.Add(6, "Banana");
        fruit.Add(7, "Peach");
        fruit.Add(8, "Plum");
        // Define the binding for the list controls.
        benimDropDownList.DataSource = fruit;
        // Choose what you want to display in the list.
        benimDropDownList.DataTextField = "Value";
        // Activate the binding.
        this.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void benimDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSonuc.Text = "You picked: " + benimDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
    lblSonuc.Text += " which has the key: " + benimDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

MainPage.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="benimDropDownList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="benimDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSonuc" runat="server"></asp:Label>  
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AutoPostBack="true"` to the `<asp:DropDownList>`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="benimDropDownList" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="benimDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

By default `<asp:DropDownList>` do not post back changes to the server.

Comment: Oh I forgotton it.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to set the DataValueField for your dropdownlist:

```
benimDropDownList.DataValueField = "Key";
```